# One-against-all probability values into a multiple class probability value?

Tags: probability, classification, ensemble-learning

I have a 10-class classification problem. I've approached the problem as a set of one-against-all binary problems. For each class I've built a MLP neural network that provides a probability estimate [0,1] as to whether the input pattern does belong to the target class. How do I combine the individual one-against-all MLP  probability estimates into a single multi-class probability estimate.

I have the idea of using $\hat{p}_j = \frac{p_j}{\sum_{i=1}^{10} p_i}$ where $\hat{p}_j$ is multi-class probability estimate for class i, and $p_j$ is the probability estimate of the one-against-all MLP for class $j$. Would this be satisfactory?

Any references would be appreciated.